# Get first image from rest api content in ionic/cordova

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, cordova, ionic-framework

I am connecting my app with the wordpress site and i have installed rest api plugins. Now i am able to display content from the json out put. Now I want to get the very first image from the retrieved content.

**CoDE**

```
"content":{"rendered":" hello hellohello hellohellohellohellohello **** < img src="" />
```

I want to extract the img.

here is my ionic code

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.latest = [];
    $scope.page = 1;
    $scope.load = function(){
        $http.get(wordpress_url+'/wp-json/wp/v2/posts' ,{
            params:{"page":$scope.page,"per_page":wordpress_per_page}
        }).then(function(response){
            if(response.data.length == 0) {
                $scope.page = $scope.page -1;
                $scope.over = true;
            }
            angular.forEach(response.data, function(item){
                item.time = new Date(item.date).getTime(); 

            });
            angular.forEach(response.data, function(item){
                $scope.latest.push(item);
            });
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
            $scope.page = $scope.page +1;
        });

    };

})
```